# Paypal IPN [Only Credit Card Transaction Failed]

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have this issue. When I pay with paypal account, everything is fine, paid successfully and IPN hit back and update my database. But when i pay with credit card option, it's paid successfully at paypal end. But when i check my logs file, i got following errors and my database is not updated because of that error.  Here is the log file.

```
    cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=20.00&protection_eligibility=Partially+Eligible+-+INR+Only&address_status=unconfirmed&payer_id=2MXXFD6AQ43BA&tax=0.00&address_street=test%0Atest&payment_date=18%3A48%3A29+May+27%2C+2011+PDT&payment_status=Pending&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=640533&first_name=test&address_country_code=SG&address_name=test+test&notify_version=3.1&custom=111%2C&payer_status=unverified&business=test_1303236553_biz%40gmail.com&address_country=Singapore&address_city=Singapore&quantity=1&verify_sign=An5ns1Kso7MWUdW4ErQKJJJ4qi4-AaEK7w348WQzfOfzLl3lrSKWYDOG&payer_email=knightrider%40gmail.com&txn_id=8H5315386S139944F&payment_type=instant&last_name=test&address_state=&receiver_email=test_1303236553_biz%40gmail.com&receiver_id=53B6G7SG6JKME&pending_reason=multi_currency&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Item&mc_currency=SGD&item_number=&residence_country=SG&test_ipn=1&receipt_id=3969-1532-6232-5707&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=111%2C&payment_gross=&shipping=0.00&ipn_track_id=smYslnsttVEUV7COBCKq5Q
    ERROR - 2011-05-28 09:48:37 --> verify fail: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Sat, 28 May 2011 01:48:36 GMT
    Server: Apache
    Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=Ye21176JM0INrH_mgX028q_y72FW1Bz126j4BoxaJRY2L6TRQAfy8NN4REbQ0zbB6qwT_dJNA1mK0kU0T0ygtxZITXeG-RFGQ7KTXslYfcnreEukYMJRfdlkHlya7vHr6rdvwW%7cteseN7TyBXzvckcwMjQeg4r6VElLIpc6dvi-MuvLWzZ05kb5xoQG-hlpVvhaqCWIjx_h00%7cyuYEQ40G78uE-mVRJmAymkg8-jr88yZUZqEtmBrsVuNlXmmsaX2r8Yn-xoUPDMvW5Y3qwW%7c1306547317; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Tue, 25-May-2021 01:48:37 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Fri, 23-May-2031 01:48:37 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: Apache=10.191.196.11.209281306547316396; path=/; expires=Thu, 13-Apr-05 19:20:20 GMT
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
INVALID
```

Comment: i would ask such specificity paypal question on their own forum

Answer (score 0):

This needs some troubleshooting . here is what I found upon googling the issue

https://www.x.com/thread/40485

https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1551

please post back what you found for others to help them.

Answer (score 0):

from paypals site:
The payment is pending because it was made via credit card and you must upgrade your account to Business or Premier status in order to receive the funds. upgrade can also mean that you have reached the monthly limit for transactions on your account.

so if youve set up your ipn to only look from "completed" transactions
youll never get a hit

so you should do two things
1)  chage your paypal account type
2)  implement a "pending" routine in your listener